# In Zend 1.11 do I put validation checks in Model or DB Model Mapper?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

in the following situation where I have a model and a model mapper I'm a bit perplexed with respect to where should I put the validation functions like for example consider the following:

```
models
-> User
-> UserMapper

Class User{

  private $id;
  private $name;
  private $email;

  }

Class UserMapper extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

  function findById($id){
  }

  function save(User $user){
  }

}
```

I need to set it so that a new user object cannot have the same email as an existing user object - where would I put the validation logic to check for this i.e in the Model or in the Model mapper? Would it be as:

```
Class UserController{

  function doAction(){
    $user = new User();
    $u = new UserMapper();
    ...
    // is this the right way to do this?
    if($user->validate()){

    }

    // or is this the right way to do this?

   if($u->validate($user)){

   }

}
}
```

Comment: How about a UNIQUE key constraint in the DB?

Answer (score 2):

Very often you would see this validation done in the registration form, you could either use the registration form object to do the validation or you could use the User object.

Either way [`Zend_Validate::DbNoRecordExists`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db) or [`Zend_Validate::DbRecordExists`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db) may prove useful and can be used as either a form validator:

```
//form demo
class Reg_Form extends Zend_Form
{  
public function init() {
   $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $name->setLabel('Name');
        $name->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Username');
        $name->setOptions(array('size' => 20));
        $name->addFilter('StringToLower');
        //truncated for brevity
        $name->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'field' => 'name'
                )));
        $this->addElement($name);
    }
}
```

or a stand alone validator in the model.

```
//Entity Model demo, This is used to check against MP3 database
/**
 * Does record already exist in DB
 *
 * Pass in the mapper to use as a string.
 * Will trigger predefined validator DbNoRecordExists
 *
 * @param string $mapper accepted values are: 'album' 'artist' 'track'
 * @return boolean returns true if no record exists
 */
protected function dbNoExist($mapper)
{
    switch ($mapper) {
        case 'album':
            $value = $this->taginfo->getAlbum();
            $options = array(
                'table'  => 'album',
                'field'  => 'title'
            );
            break;
        case 'artist':
            $value = $this->taginfo->getArtist();
            $options = array(
                'table'  => 'artist',
                'field'  => 'name'
            );
            break;
        case 'track':
            $value = $this->taginfo->getMd5();
            $options = array(
                'table' => 'track',
                'field' => 'hash'
            );
    }
    $validator = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists($options);
    if ($validator->isValid($value)) {
        //no record exists
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        //record exists
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The way I try to answer these questions in my projects is:

If I change my data persistence from MySql to a flat file(or some other method), would I still need this action(validation) to occur?

If so the code goes into the entity model (User). If not then the code would go into the mapper. I realize this is kind of simplistic, but it usually gets me going the right direction.

**[EDIT]**

Personally I'm going to do this small bit of validation before the form even posts if possible. I want to let the user know if he already has an account with that email before he posts the form, saves both of us time and frustration. Final validation can always be accomplished in the User Model.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Any complex logic or validation related to a database table should be go to the 'model' class (User). Don't put them inside Table class (UserMapper).

In your case, the model class name is 'User';

I follow below approach for a duplicate email checking.

1. Include the 'Model Mapper' file (UserMapper.php) in Model file (User.php)
2. Create a  public STATIC method named 'isEmailDuplicate($emailAddress)' inside Model class (User). Inside this function, create object of the Mapper class (UserMapper.php) and perform select query using 'Zend_Db_select'( [help link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html))  over the Mapper class object (UserMapper.php). Finally return the Boolean result to the caller.
3. Call the Model function from UserController.
   $isEmailDuplicate = User::isEmailDuplicate($emailAddress);

Comment: I like the idea of a sTatic method in the model - but doesnt the Model represent the User Object. Logically is this something that the User Object would be doing?